# SQL dealing with subqueries Error Code: 1111

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1111

[image]

I'm trying to learn some SQL, so I've been messing around with the sample world schema. For this query, the goal is, for each continent, to retrieve the capitals of the countries in which life expectancy is greater than the average for that continent.

The code below is my attempt at that, but I receive an **1111 error** on the where statement. any help would be much appreciated!

```sql
SELECT continent AS Continent,
       city.name AS Capital
FROM city,
     country c1
WHERE c1.capital = city.id
  AND avg(LifeExpectancy) <
    (SELECT avg(LifeExpectancy)
     FROM country c2
     WHERE c2.continent = c1.continent );
```

Comment: If you are learning SQL, then learn `JOIN` and `ON`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Well then feel free to make this a learning opportunity. how would you recommend using JOIN and ON to help with this?

Comment: @GenghisConn post sample data and expected results to clarify. As it is your question it's not clear which columns belong to which tables.

Comment: @forpas good point, I have attached the EER Diagram to the original post now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your problem statement, you would not need avg life expectancy of the capital, just the life expectancy of the country corresponding to the capital greater than the average for that continent. So, I made those adjustments in the query below.

Let me know this works.

```
SELECT continent AS Continent,
       city.name AS Capital
FROM city,
     country c1
WHERE c1.capital = city.id
  AND c1.LifeExpectancy >
    (SELECT avg(LifeExpectancy)
     FROM country c2
     WHERE c2.continent = c1.continent );
```

Answer (score 1):

You must join properly the tables `country` and `city` to a query that returns the average `lifeexpectancy` for each continent:

```
select co.code, ci.name
from country co
inner join city ci on ci.id = co.capital
inner join (
  select continent, avg(lifeexpectancy) avg_lifeexpectancy
  from country
  group by continent
) t on t.continent = co.continent and t.avg_lifeexpectancy < co.lifeexpectancy
```